# data wrangling in R - collapse rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data structured like this:

|  | gene | sample1 | sample2 | sample3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 0.2 | NA | NA |
| 2 | B | 0.1 | NA | NA |
| 3 | C | -0.3 | NA | NA |
| 4 | A | NA | -0.3 | NA |
| 5 | B | NA | 0.5 | NA |
| 6 | C | NA | NA | NA |
| 7 | A | NA | NA | NA |
| 8 | B | NA | NA | 0.2 |
| 9 | C | NA | NA | -0.5 |

I need to collapse the rows by `gene`, keeping all values, including `NA`, so that the final dataframe looks like:

|  | gene | sample1 | sample2 | sample3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 0.2 | -0.3 | NA |
| 2 | B | 0.1 | 0.5 | 0.2 |
| 3 | C | -0.3 | NA | -0.5 |

There are ~400 sample columns and ~5M rows. I've tried the following:

```
df %>% group_by(gene) %>% summarize(across(everything(), ~ ifelse(all(is.na(.x)), NA, max(.x, na.rm = FALSE))))
```

But I'm losing some data...any other dplyr solutions (or tweaks to `summarize()` above)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach looks good to me, if you set `na.rm = TRUE`. Can you provide an example where you actually loose data? I assume that you just want to keep the maximum value, at least, this is what you code suggests.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(gene) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(),
                   ~ ifelse(all(is.na(.x)),
                            NA,
                            max(.x, na.rm = TRUE)
                            )
                   )
            )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   gene  sample1 sample2 sample3
#>   <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 A         0.2    -0.3    NA  
#> 2 B         0.1     0.5     0.2
#> 3 C        -0.3    NA      -0.5
```

Data from OP

```r
df <- tribble(~ gene, ~ sample1, ~ sample2, ~ sample3,

   "A",     0.2     , NA     , NA     ,  
   "B",     0.1     , NA     , NA     ,  
   "C",     -0.3    , NA     , NA     ,  
   "A",     NA      , -0.3   , NA     ,  
   "B",     NA      , 0.5    , NA     ,  
   "C",     NA      , NA     , NA     ,  
   "A",     NA      , NA     , NA     ,  
   "B",     NA      , NA     , 0.2    ,  
   "C",     NA      , NA     , -0.5 )
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This worked once I set `na.rm = TRUE`. I initially thought I was dropping data based on the input gene count, but it turns out there were duplicated genes and those were dropped by keeping max value...my mistake! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, \(s) max(s[!is.na(s)])), gene]
```

Output:

```
     gene sample1 sample2 sample3
   <char>   <num>   <num>   <num>
1:      A     0.2    -0.3      NA
2:      B     0.1     0.5     0.2
3:      C    -0.3      NA    -0.5
```

Comment: This also works, but doesn't remove instances of duplicated genes with values in each column.

Comment: just wrap in `max()'.  see edit